# Dreamweaver shortcut to swap between source and dependent files

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, dreamweaver

Dreamweaver (CS 5.5) displays source code and dependent files as sub-tabs (?).

[image: View of source code and dependent files in Dreamweaver]

You can swap between tabs control+shift+tab, but how to swap between source and dependent files?

Answer (score 2):

This issue has bothered me for a long time now, and I am pleased to say I have found a partial solution to it. There is no keyboard shortcut for switching between related (dependent) files, however there is a shortcut called "Go to Source Code", which by default is Ctrl+Alt+`.

Optional: This shortcut (and any other shortcut) can also be edited via the "Keyboard Shortcuts" menu which can be found under the "Edit" tab. To do so, from within said menu, choose the "Dreamweaver Standard" as the "Current set", and click the most left button amongst the 4 buttons at the top, called "Duplicate set". This will allow you to create a duplicate set of Shortcuts, with a name of your choice. Once that's done, you will be able to find the "Go to Source Code" shortcut by selecting "Document editing" from the "Commands" select box. This shortcut should be the second last. To change the keyboard sequence for it, click on it, insert a new "Press key", click the "Change" button and then the "OK" button to accept the changes.

As for switching to related files, this can be done via View->Related Files. This is clearly not nearly as instant as using a designated keyboard shortcut, but remember, the issue was having to use the mouse in order to switch to related files, and this method allows you to do so by using the keyboard alone (Alt+arrows).