# Keyboard shortcut for switching between html and css sheets in Dreamweaver?

Tags: tabs, keyboard, dreamweaver, shortcut

I often have to switch between html, css and javascript sheets in Dreamweaver. As far as I know, there's no shortcut to do this. It's annoying having to use the mouse do it.

I know I can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to switch between html sheets.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the following thread, in which I have just answered this exact same question:

[Dreamweaver shortcut to swap between source and dependent files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12506802/dreamweaver-shortcut-to-swap-between-source-and-dependent-files)

Liran